# Returning the value of an attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#target").click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("width"));
        });
    });
 </script>

<style>
    #target {
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
        background-color:#0094ff;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
 </body>
```

I am trying to return the attribute value of an html element.(Here: width(attribute) of the target(html element)).
But it alerts "undefined" for me.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting width property of css not an html attribute  (also for your information , html attribute "width" is deprecated) to access the css property width use :

```
$("#target").click(function () {
    alert($(this).css("width"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#target").click(function () {
        alert($(this).css("width"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").click(function () {
    alert($('#target').width()); //300: always returns integer as px unit
    alert($('#target').css('width')); //300px: return width with string with suffix "px"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking to get the css height property, instead you are trying to get the attribute of your div. Instead you should try with `.css(prop)` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#target").click(function () {
        alert($(this).css("width"));
    });
});
```

Your question:

*But it alerts "undefined" for me. Do u have any idea why?!!*

As i have written above you were trying to get the attribute of your div like *(which in your case is not there.)*:

```
<div id="target" width='500'></div>
<!---------------^^^this^^^-->
```

That is attribute width of your `#target` div. That is the main cause of alerting `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

try this may this will help you

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#target").click(function () {
        $(this).setAttribute("width", "480");

    });
    });
```